# How can I define @transactional an Identity Manager?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In the spring config file I have the following beans:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="EntryPU" />
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

When the application call the method "remove":

```
@Override
public void remove(int id) {
    entry = entityManager.find(Entry.class, id);
    entityManager.remove(entry);
}
```

the log says:

```
No transactional EntityManager available.
```

How can I make it transactional ?

Comment: Just want to ask have you create a "dataSource" bean for the reference property under "entityManagerFactory" bean? because it doesn't show in the provided spring config file snippet

Answer (score 1):

Add @Transactional to the method for make it run inside a transaction.

```
@Transactional @Override
public void remove(int id) {
    entry = entityManager.find(Entry.class, id);
    entityManager.remove(entry);
}
```

Comment: That's what I did, but then when I run the web application it shows a empty page.

Comment: @MdC:  Does the error about a non-transactional entity manager still show up after trying this?

Comment: I cant' see the error because I cant' reach the remove page. It shows a white page